# Опишите стилистические и жанровые особенности

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, лексикография, общие-вопросы, стили-речи

Подскажите как описать стилистические и жанровые особенности "доверенности 
на право распоряжения имуществом" по следующему плану: 
1. Сфера употребления текста
2. Доминирующая функция языка 
3. Цель создания данного конкретного текста
4. Вид и форма речи
5. Стиль текста
6. Стилевая разновидность (подстиль)
7. Лексические особенности текста (указать наиболее типичные для данного 
стиля и жанра слова и обороты на примерах из собственного текста)

Answer (score 1):

Вот клише доверенности. Его и анализируем.

http://www.notarius-spb.ru/useful/dovimush.html

1-официальная сфера, документ.

2-информирование, констатация факта

3-создание документа:информирование о переходе права распоряжения имуществом другому лицу, закрепление этого права документально.

4- письменная речь

5-официально-деловой

6-канцелярско-деловой

7-лексика:термины юриспруденции (заключать сделки,),речевые штампы и канцелярские клише: уполномочиваю...управлять и распоряжаться всем моим имуществом, в чем бы оно ни заключалось и где бы оно ни находилось,прекращение и возникновение права собственности

отсутствие разговорной и эмоционально окрашенной лексики

• Слова и словосочетания указывающие на обязательность закона (имеет право, гарантируются, вправе, обязан, обязательно, обеспечивают, устанавливает, поддерживает и под.).

•  Перифразы – словосочетания, состоящие из глагола и существительного, имеющие нейтральные однословные синонимы: предоставляю право=разрешаю,быть законным представителем=представлять
и т.д.